# Unable to create VRT file of COG GeoTIFF imagery files located on AWS using QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, vrt

I've attempted several ways to get the "Build Virtual Raster" tool in QGIS 3.26.2 to build a .vrt file using (https:...). It works fine with the same files if I previously download them, but I get the error "Incorrect parameter value for INPUT" when I try to access them on the web. I've tried accessing the files both with and without the /vsiurl/ prepend, and I get the same error. The Python code below is copied from the tool dialog, then I edited it and ran it in the Python Console.

> processing.run("gdal:buildvirtualraster", {'INPUT':['
> /vsicurl/https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Elevation/1m/Projects/IN_Indiana_Statewide_LiDAR_2017_B17/TIFF/USGS_1M_16_x65y432_IN_Indiana_Statewide_LiDAR_2017_B17.tif','
> /vsicurl/https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Elevation/1m/Projects/IN_Indiana_Statewide_LiDAR_2017_B17/TIFF/USGS_1M_16_x64y436_IN_Indiana_Statewide_LiDAR_2017_B17.tif'],'RESOLUTION':0,'SEPARATE':False,'PROJ_DIFFERENCE':False,'ADD_ALPHA':False,'ASSIGN_CRS':None,'RESAMPLING':0,'SRC_NODATA':'','EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
>
> **Traceback (most recent call last):**
>
> File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
> exec(code, self.locals) File "", line 1, in File
> "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py",
> line 108, in run return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters,
> onFinish, feedback, context) File
> "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py",
> line 181, in runAlgorithm raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
> _core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
>
> **Incorrect parameter value for INPUT**

Comment: Is it a free bucket or a "requester pays" bucket?

Comment: It's a public bucket.  I discovered the public folder path to the file was slightly different than using the internal AWS file path, but the /vsicurl/ prepend is still an issue.  An example of the correct path and file name is...

https://gisimageryingov.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imageryoptimized/statewide/2022/SPE/03in/in2022_2475_1600_03.tif

Thanks.